# modificacion de hora en una fecha con javascript y mostrar en tipo getTime()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Cordial saludo comunidad,

Tengo una fecha en una variable llamada de la siguiente manera

```
var plazo_respuesta
```

esta me arroja una fecha como la sigueinte:

**Tue May 10 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)**

ahora tengo otra variable que me trae una hora en especifico

```
var Horaplazo
```

y se muestra de la siguiente manera:

**23:35**

lo que necesito es cambiar la hora en plazo_respuesta por la hora de Horaplazo

tengo de la siguiente manera la fecha como indican en las repuestas de la siguiente manera

```
var plazo_respuesta = new Date(listas['spot'][0].plazo_respuesta.date.substring(0, 10));
var Horaplazo = (listas['spot'][0].horaRespuesta);
    
    if(Horaplazo == null){
        var Horaplazo = '23:55';
        console.log(Horaplazo);
    }else{
        var Horaplazo = listas['spot'][0].horaRespuesta.date.substring(11, 16);
        console.log(Horaplazo); 
    }
    
    /** En el siguiente se unifica la fecha de plazo de respuesta y hora de respuesta ya que estos dos son campos separados*/
    
    var [hora, min] = Horaplazo.split(":")
    console.log(hora)
    plazo_respuesta.setHours(hora)
    plazo_respuesta.setMinutes(min)
    var horaPlazorespt = plazo_respuesta;
    console.log(horaPlazorespt);
```

esto me muesta la siguiente hora con la hora modificada

```
Fri Jun 03 2022 23:38:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)
```

pero necesito que esa nueva fecha con la hora formateada me quede en una variable con el getTime(). para que me quede en formato numerico esa variable, lo he intentado de esta forma pero no me toma la fecha con la hora modificada.

```
console.log(horaPlazorespt.getTime());
```

esta me arroja lo siguiente, que es la forma en que lo necesito pero no me toma los minutos de la misma:

```
1654317480000
```

Muchas gracias y quedo pendiente

Comment: para sacar la diferencias de tiempo es recomendable utiliza la siguiente librería  utilizando la siguiente función [momentjs](  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) 
 `a.diff(b, 'hours', true); `

Comment: Aparte de pedir lo que quieres, debes demostrar que lo has intentado de alguna forma para que la pregunta cumpla con lo explicado en [ask] y [example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo por el formato que adjuntas, que `plazo_respuesta` es de tipo `Date` y `Horaplazo` es de tipo `string`, es muy sencillo establecer la hora y los minutos usando los métodos de Date `setHours` y `setMinutes`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
var plazo_respuesta = new Date(2022,4,10,19,0,0);
var Horaplazo = "23:35"

console.log("Fecha Inicial: " + plazo_respuesta)

var [hora, min] = Horaplazo.split(":")
plazo_respuesta.setHours(hora)
plazo_respuesta.setMinutes(min)

console.log("Fecha Modificada: " + plazo_respuesta)
```